# Upload large files using a REST API and a Node.js middleware

Tags: node.js, stream, next.js13

I currently have a Next.js application that handles file uploads.

The client app has a simple form and upload input.

I want to send files as a `ReadableStream` from the client application to the Next server (using [route hanlder](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers)).

This should then send the file to our backend service via a Rest API.

I'm using fetch on the client app and to send data to the rest api.

I can see that from client -> node middleware the post data is sent as a readable stream. I just can't work out how to forward that to the backend without either saving the file on the server Next is running on or saving it to memory (in node).

Ideally I'd like to `pipe` the stream to the backend.

I can see that `ReadableStream` has a [pipeTo method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/pipeTo) but I can't quite piece it all together.

I'm not even sure if what i want to achieve is possible.

Any help would be incredible!

## Side notes

The upload has to go to our backend through the middleware, we can't use presigned URLs or anything like that.

I was hoping to basically send the readable stream straight to the backend in another fetch request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly about Next.js but I use the `express-fileupload` package, to send files to a node.js backend. From the front end (usually, react), form data is made and the file is sent in the body.

You can try that. Or there is another popular package called `multer`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My main question is if it's possible to maintain a stream through 2 fetch requests without having to save the file somewhere in between.